# Error loading video with file-transfer plugin error code 3, exception: "Broken pipe"

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm having a problem trying to upload a video using cordova-plugin-file-transfer.

Where this.video equals file: ///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20210706_134119.mp4

code:

```
uploadVideo(idPublicacion) {
this.alertas.presentLoading('Wait, please');
this.fileTransfer = this.transfer.create();
let options: FileUploadOptions = {
fileKey: 'video',
fileName: new Date().getTime() + ".mp4",
httpMethod: 'POST',
// chunkedMode: false,
headers: {
"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
'authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token
},
mimeType: 'video/mp4'
}
this.uploadText = "uploading...";
this.fileTransfer.upload(this.video,
http://ec2-54-167-83-212.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/jagersocial_back/api/social/uploadVideo?idPublicacion=${idPublicacion} ,
options).then(async (data) => {
alert("transferencia hecha = " + JSON.stringify(data));
this.uploadText = "";
this.alertas.dismissLoading();
await this.modalController.dismiss(this.description);
}, (errorTransfer) => {
console.log('Error de transfer: ', errorTransfer);
this.uploadText = "";
this.alertas.dismissLoading();
});
}
```

The resources used for the project are:

```
Ionic:

Ionic CLI : 5.4.6 (C:\Users\galac\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
Ionic Framework : @ionic/angular 4.11.10
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1000.5
@angular-devkit/schematics : 8.1.3
@angular/cli : 10.0.5
@ionic/angular-toolkit : 2.2.0

Cordova:

Cordova CLI : 10.0.0
Cordova Platforms : android 9.1.0
Cordova Plugins : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 20 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res : 0.8.1
native-run : 0.2.8

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\galac\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
NodeJS : v10.16.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm : 7.16.0
OS : Windows 10
```

Cordova Plugins:

```
com-badrit-base64 0.2.0 "Base64"
    
com-sarriaroman-photoviewer 1.2.4 "PhotoViewer"
    
cordova-plugin-advanced-http 2.4.1 "Advanced HTTP plugin"
    
cordova-plugin-android-permissions 1.0.2 "Permissions"
    
cordova-plugin-camera 4.1.0 "Camera"
    
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"
    
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1 "File Transfer"
    
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2 "File"
    
cordova-plugin-filechooser 1.2.0 "File Chooser"
    
cordova-plugin-filepath 1.6.0 "cordova-plugin-filepath"
    
cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio 3.0.1 "FingerprintAllInOne"
    
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.2 "Geolocation"
    
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
    
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
    
cordova-plugin-media-capture 3.0.3 "Capture"
    
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.2 "Network Information"
    
cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy 2.3.0 "Request Location Accuracy"
    
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.3 "Splashscreen"
    
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.3 "StatusBar"
    
cordova-plugin-streaming-media 2.3.0 "StreamingMedia"
    
cordova-plugin-video-editor 1.1.3 "VideoEditor"
    
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"
    
cordova-sqlite-storage 4.0.0 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin - cordova-sqlite-storage plugin version"
```

I also share a screenshot of the error sent by the file-trasnfer plugin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqzcf.png)

If someone can help me I would appreciate it very much

Comment: Error code 3 is connection error (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer#constants). How big video do you try to upload?